# Can you set different CALayer border width on different side?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am trying to create a pseudo-3D square (like a scrabble tile) and I was thinking of faking it with borders. But then I couldn't find a way to set different width for different side.

Is this possible at all? If not, does anyone have any recommendation on how to do this in CALayer?

Oh, one caveat, I am already using shadow, so can't use that to fake the bevel.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with ordinary CALayer properties. You'd have to inset your layer and draw the different borders in the drawing method, or add a second larger layer to take care of that inside its drawing.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do it with the layer's shadow properties, using -shadowOffset to only render it on two sides. However, to make it really nice you probably have to draw it yourself.